# How to use namespace in php?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm developing a solution that i need use `Amazon WebServices` library. Their library use namespace in all the project and how i am a beginner in `PHP` development i need your help to understand better how it works.

Here is my class:

```
<?php

// include('AmazonSNS\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Sdk.php');
// include('AmazonSNS\model\CustomCredentials.php');

use Aws\Sdk;

class AwsSns {
        public $sns;
        public $platformApplicationArn;


        public function __construct(){
            $sdk = new Sdk([
                'version'  => 'latest',
                'debug'    => false,
                'retries'  => 3,
                'credentials' => [
                    'key'    => CustomCredentials::SNS_KEY,
                    'secret' => CustomCredentials::SNS_SECRET
                ],
                'Sns' => [
                    'region'  => 'sa-east-1'
                ]
            ]);

            $this->sns = $sdk->createSns();
            $this->generatePlatformApplicationArn();
        }


        private function generatePlatformApplicationArn( ){
            $result = $this->sns->createPlatformApplication( array(
                // Name is required
                'Name' => 'GCMPedro',
                // Platform is required
                'Platform' => 'GCM',
                // Attributes is required
                'Attributes' => array(
                    // Associative array of custom 'String' key names
                    'PlatformCredential' => "AIzaSyBYjNaE7ShuLc2y4mf53bVwszDt8XA-YTI" //__API_KEY__
                ),
            ));
            $this->platformApplicationArn = $result->get('PlatformApplicationArn');

            Util::generateFile('PlataformApplicationArn: '.$this->platformApplicationArn, 'a');
        }


        public function getEndpointArn( $token ){
            $result = $this->sns->createPlatformEndpoint(array(
                // PlatformApplicationArn is required
                'PlatformApplicationArn' => $this->platformApplicationArn,
                // Token is required
                'Token' => $token,
                //'CustomUserData' => 'string',
                'Attributes' => array(
                    // Associative array of custom 'String' key names
                    'Enabled' => 'true'
                ),
            ));

            Util::generateFile('EndpointArn: '.$result->get('EndpointArn'), 'a');

            return( $result->get('EndpointArn') );
        }
    }

?>
```

1) About name space, to use it, Do have I include or not include the `.php` file?

Observation:

When i don't use the include, the php returns the following error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Sdk' not found in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\AmazonSNS\extra\AwsSns.php on line 14

Sure of your attention i thank you so much.

Comment: 1) Namespace is just for logical separation of your code. This way you can have class/function/variable/constant with the same name but in different namespaces. Plus, instead of using FQN (Fully Qualified Name) you may use shorter names. 2) Using namespace does not mean that require/include statements are no longer required. 3) This question has nothing to do with PhpStorm itself -- I'm removing that tag.

Comment: Some links (after quick googling for "php namespaces tutorial"): 1) http://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/ 2) http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/ 3) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3SvDAoODr8

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LazyOne. It was userful for me. Analyzing my code, do you have any suggestion to help me to solve my problem? When i remove the ìnclude`the `PHP`returns the error above.

Comment: Why do you need to remove `include`? That's can only be done if 1) you are including it somewhere else or 2) you are using class autoloading (be it your own function or by using standard Composer functionality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you haven't set up an autoloading like [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) or [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) (like in the common PHP frameworks is used) or something else, the neccessary file **is not** going to be loaded/included automatically when its being called. I guess you haven't such an autoloading set up, so you can include with the `include` keyword.

In the [official documentation of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) you can read all about namespaces.

Citate of the manual. 2 benefits:

> In the PHP world, namespaces are designed to solve two problems that authors of libraries and applications encounter when creating re-usable code elements such as classes or functions:
>
> 1. Name collisions between code you create, and internal PHP classes/functions/constants or third-party classes/functions/constants.
> 2. Ability to alias (or shorten) Extra_Long_Names designed to alleviate the first problem, improving readability of source code.